# Unable to use ingress-nginx for routing on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, ingress-nginx

I was trying to use Kubernetes to set up a service locally. I am using ingress-nginx for routing. I am using Ubuntu 18.04. This is my ingress.yaml file:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata: 
  name: ingress-service
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: 'true'
spec: 
  rules:
    - host: ecommerce.dev
      http:   
        paths: 
          - path: /api/users/?(.*) 
            backend: 
              serviceName: auth-srv
              servicePort: 3000
```

Also, I mapped this in my `/etc/hosts/` file:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   TALHA

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters

127.0.0.1 ecommerce.dev
```

When I try to reach 'ecommerce.dev' from my browser, I am unable to access it as it says 'Site can not be reached'. Can someone please help me about it?

Comment: How did you deploy ingress-nginx? Can you provide the yamls?

Comment: I'd also like you to test sth. Find the nginx-ingress service's NodePort and go to `ecommerce.dev:<NodePort>`. Does it work?

Comment: Here's my code for ingress-serv.yaml:  https://pastebin.com/nEFaQknc and here's my code for skaffold : https://pastebin.com/tazvJSxs

Comment: @Matt I tired it with the NodePort, and it did not work.

Comment: no, not the nginx-service, I mean the nginx ingress conrtoller. How did you deploy the ingress-nginx controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I saw you mentioned you are using minikube with nginx ingress addon.

This information helps a lot. Try not to skip this kind of information in future. I was assuming that by saying *"I was trying to use Kubernetes to set up a service locally"* you mean that you run baremetal k8s.

Minikube is most probably running in a VM and this is why you cannot access it.

Running `minikube ip` gives you the IP address of a VM:

```
$ minikube ip
192.168.39.67
```

Your ip may be different so don't use my IP, check what IP you got assigned.

Now that you have the IP of a minikube VM, use it in `/etc/hosts`. In my case it looks like following:

```
192.168.39.67 ecommerce.dev
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man! Sorry I am a beginner to Kubernetes, hence the confusion. I will read from docs the next time I try.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed nginx-ingress using Helm you could:

1. Add `--service-node-port-range=80-32767` on `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml`.
2. Set the service type to `NodePort` so that you can expose it publicly through port 80 and 443.

```sh
kubectl patch svc ingress-nginx-controller -p '{"spec": {"type": "NodePort"}}'
```

3. Change the default generated ports of the `nginx-ingress-controller` service to 80 and 443.

```
kubectl patch svc ingress-nginx-controller -p '{"spec": {"ports": [{"name": "http", "nodePort": 80, "port": 80, "protocol": "TCP", "targetPort": "http"}, {"name": "https", "nodePort": 443, "port": 443, "protocol": "TCP", "targetPort": "https"}]}}'
```

This steps would only open the ports 80 and 443 of your `nginx-ingress-controller` service. If it does not solve your problem then it's probably related to your proxy.

Comment: I installed ingress using minikube. `minikube addons enable ingress`